# Maximize active window in terminator

Tags: shortcut-keys, terminator

I am on xenial and using terminator 0.98.

When I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, terminator opens up a new window.

Sometimes its convenient to maximize the window that was opened.
Is there a keyboard shortcut to do that?

I have tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and nothing happens.

Pardon me if I am too naive here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

On my standard 16.04 this shortcut allows me to maximize the active window.
There is also:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to restore/minimize windows.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> to dock a window to the left/right half of the screen.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 32):

To toggle the current of multiple terminals within Terminator between maximized and restored state, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

To use the default window manager keybinding to maximize your Terminator window, see [Forivin's answer on this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/876852/11052).

Comment: I went looking and `man terminator` actually says this, despite the online manual making no mention that this shortcut is a toggle. it would be great to add a "Toggle" to the Options column in this table: https://terminator-gtk2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html?highlight=restore#using-the-keyboard

Comment: The Terminator manual linked here has a section on [getting involved by improving the docs](https://terminator-gtk2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettinginvolved.html#manual-updates). Do it! :)